# AzureRmRoleAssignment Access denied to the specified API version

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm getting an error running `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment`. I want to give an AD group access to a resource group. The script actually works-- the group gets contributor access to the resource group. It just says that it's failing with the message "Access denied to the specified API version".

My script (params not included) is here:

```
# Import the Task.Common dll that has all the cmdlets we need for Build
import-module Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Common
import-module Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal
Import-Module "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Deployment.Internal"
Import-Module "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Deployment.Azure"

Write-Output "Connecting to Azure"
Initialize-AzurePowershellSupport -ConnectedServiceName $ConnectedServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$subscription = (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionName #(Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionName

New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objID -RoleDefinitionName $roleName -ResourceGroupName $environment-$featureName
```

How can I fix the error? The script does what it's supposed to, but the build "fails".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error log, do you login Azure by using  service principal. If yes, it is a know issue. Please check the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1896) on GitHub. The issue is solved on the latest version Azure Power Shell(4.1.0 or later).

You could use the following cmdlet to check your Azure PowerShell version.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

The latest version is 4.3.1, you could download it from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

If you build the script on VSTS, please use `Hosted 2017 build agent`, it uses the latest version PowerShell. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858925/how-to-use-latest-azurerm-in-a-vsts-task/45873639#45873639).

Comment: When I build it with Hosted 2017, I get "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown." The user building the resource has contributor+roleassign.

Comment: @user3364161 I test in my lab, `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId "dc02841e-7c25-4bc9-a7df-12c3c34410b2" -RoleDefinitionName "contributor" -ResourceGroupName "shuihv"`. It works for me. I suggest you could test on your local PowerShell, if you get the same error log, it seems a permission of your Azure AD account, you need give grap Api for your account. Please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3407).

Comment: @user3364161 There is a mistake in your script. `$subscription = (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionName` The cmdlet could not get subscription Name. You could use `$subscription = (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.Name`

Comment: I don't think it was a problem with subscription. It was connecting to the subscription since the change was made. When I tried running it locally as owner, it said I don't have permission to perform the roleassignment/write action. Does this mean it's a problem with the graph api?

Comment: @user3364161 It is very strange. I test in my lab. The objectId `dc02841e-7c25-4bc9-a7df-12c3c34410b2` is a service principal. If possible, could you create a new service principal and test again.

Comment: I updated Powershell and AzurePS on the build server, and instead of the old error I got the error that it gets on Hosted2017: "Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown at Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC". I can't change the service principal. I think it's a problem with the Graph API, what permissions are necessary for build servers working through VSTS?

Comment: @user3364161 Your build server is your own VM, not VSTS agent? For test, you could give all permission to your service principal.

Comment: I ended up finding a workaround after updating my powershell/azureps